# How to use Storage Buffers in WGPU to store dynamic sized arrays

Tags: rust, gpu, wgpu-rs, wgsl

I am working on a Pathtracer that uses the fragment-shader to render onto a Texture.

Currently I only render Spheres that are stored as a UniformBuffer like this:

```
var<uniform> geometry: Geometry;
struct Geometry {
    sphere_count: u32,
    spheres: array<Sphere, MAX_SPHERES>,
};
struct Sphere {
    position: vec3<f32>,
    color: vec3<f32>,
    radius: f32,
    roughness: f32,
};
```

But I want to render a variable amount of Voxel-Grids and because the size of one UniformBuffer seems to be limited to only 2^16 bytes I thought I would be a good Idea to store them in an array of 3D textures.

Is it possible to have all my textures in only one BindGroup like this:

```
var<uniform> texture_data: TextureData;
struct TextureData {
    texture_count: u32,
    texture_views: array<texture_3d<u32>, MAX_TEXTURES>;
    sampler: sampler;
};
```

Or is there any better way I could approach this problem?

## Edit

I think using Storage Buffers is a better way but I have difficulties accessing dynamic sized arrays

I have the chunk-data stored like this on the shader:

```
var<storage, read> chunks: array<Chunk>;
struct Chunk {
    position: vec3<i32>,
    data: array<u32, CHUNK_SIZE>,
};
```

and in another uniform I have the total amount of chunks stored.

But when I try to access the chunks like this:

```
for (var index = 0u; index < globals.chunk_count; index = index + 1u) {
    let chunk = chunks[index];
}
```

The Program just hangs while creating the render pipeline.

If i replace `chunks[index]` with `chunks[0]` it seems to work.

I currently do not initialize the buffer with any data, so nothing is written to it upon its creation, but even when writing data to it to fill one `Chunk` in the array nothing is changed.

the Rust `Chunk` looks like this:

```rust
pub struct Chunk {
    position: [i32; 3],
    _padding: u32,
    data: [u32; TOTAL_CHUNK_SIZE],
}
```

Even when filling the whole buffer, which size I have set during `device.create_buffer()` with zeroes does seemingly nothing.

What is the proper way of using Storage buffers in WGPU to store dynamic sized arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all was just a problem of memory alignment.

Changing the wgsl code to:

```
@group(3)
@binding(0)
var<storage, read> chunks: array<Chunk>;
struct Chunk {
    position: vec3<i32>,
    metadata: u32,
    data: array<vec4<u32>, CHUNK_SIZE>,
};
```

Seems to fix the problem.

I am assuming that the array stride of `data` must be a multiple of 16 so i changed `u32` to `vec4<u32>` and quartered `CHUNK_SIZE`.

I also added `metadata` to align `data` to 16 bytes.

Comment: is "must be a multiple of 16" mentioned in the spec?

Comment: Yes, in the spec at https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#alignment-and-size, the `AlignOf(vec3<f32>)` is explicitly listed as 16. Perhaps there's no better way to create an aligned `array<vec3<u32>>` than the method above.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused due to required alignment of 16 for storage and uniform bindings as the author's answer explains (and wgpu/naga returns a warning (now)).

Greater alignment can be achieved via the [align attribute](https://gpuweb.github.io/gpuweb/wgsl/#attribute-align). The attribute can't be applied to the binding directly as it's a structure member attribute so if one wants only to bind a `vec<u32>`, it's neccessary to wrap it in a struct and *then* apply the `@align(16)` attribute.

So a binding:

```
@group(0) @binding(0) var<uniform> my_binding: array<u32>;
```

then becomes:

```
struct MyWrapper {
  @align(16)
  value: array<u32>,
}
@group(0) @binding(0) var<uniform> my_binding: MyWrapper;
```

In this example I used a `uniform` binding, but same applies to `storage` - my problem was the same requirement on a `uniform` binding.